# Expanded navigation by default

Tags: php, magento, module, navigation

I use the Sidebar Navigation Menu Professional for Magento by CODNITIVE and I am trying to make it expanded by default. Particularly I need a solution to make just the first list item expanded by default. I try to edit Navigation.php in app/code/community/codnitive/sidenav/block/:

```
    $collapsibleClass = '';
    if ($config->isCollapsible()) {
        $collapsibleClass = ' collapsible';
    }

    // add collapsible arrow and wrraper
    $arrow = '';
    $extraStyle = '';
    $collapsibleIconPosition = $config->getCollapsibleIconPosition();
    if ($config->isCollapsible()) {
        $width = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() === 'arrow' ? 8 : 16;
        $height = 0;
        $expanded = 0;
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $width = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() === 'arrow' ? 8 : 16;
            $height = 16;
        }
        if ($height == 0) {
            $extraStyle = ' display:none;';
        }
        if ($height == 0 && $collapsibleIconPosition === 'left') {
            $liMarginLeft += $width;
        }
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $expanded = 1;
        }

        $expanded = ' expanded="' . $expanded .'"';
        $spanOnclick = 'onclick="Codnitive.expandMenu(this.parentNode)';
        $spanClass   = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() . '-' . $collapsibleIconPosition;
        $arrow = '<span class="' . $spanClass . ' " ' . $spanOnclick . '" style="width: ' . $width . 'px; height: ' . $height . 'px;' . $extraStyle . '"></span>';
    }
```

If I add this code to make the desired category expanded

```
        if ($category->getId() == '35') {
        $expanded = 1;
    }
```

there appear two problems:

1. The category remains expanded even if another category is active.
2. The "plus" sign (showing that the category can be expanded) remains but it should be "minus". I guess $collapsibleIconPosition should be 'right'?

   ```
           if ($height == 0 && $collapsibleIconPosition === 'left') {
           $liMarginLeft += $width;
       }
   ```

Comment: If you showed us the HTML from the menu, I could show you a javascript-less solution. (CSS/HTML attribute)

Comment: @whitehat101 I added the HTML above.

Comment: @capola check my answer I added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute that javascript anytime after (enough of) your HTML has loaded.

If your site uses `jQuery`, you can put it in a ready callback:

```
$(function(){
    Codnitive.expand(document.getElementById('the-menu-parent-element-id'))
})
```

You can put it at the very end of your html document, or at least after all the navigation HTML code.

```
...
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Codnitive.expand(document.getElementById('the-menu-parent-element-id'))
  </script>
</body>
```

Or you can put it in a `onload` callback. (**warning**: *this might interfere with other javascript on your site*) If there is an existing `window.onload`, it is safe to add it at the beginning or end of that function.

```
window.onload = function(){
  Codnitive.expand(document.getElementById('the-menu-parent-element-id'))
}
```

---

The element you want to target is: `<ul class="level0 collapsible" ...`

It doesn't have a `id` currently, so you can't directly use `getElementById()`.

**One solution** (not my favorite approach) would be to add an `id`

`<ul id="start-open" class="level0 collapsible" ...`

And then expand it:

`Codnitive.expand(document.getElementById('start-open'))`

I think **the best solution** would be to modify the HTML to do what `expand` would do to it:

```
<li class="level0 nav-1 first parent collapsible" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="plus-right " onclick="Codnitive.expandMenu(this.parentNode)" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;background-position: right center"></span>

<a class="collapsible-wrapper collapse-name" onclick="Codnitive.expandMenu(this.parentNode);return false;" href="#"><span class="category_name">WANT TO BE EXPANDED BY DEFAULT</span></a>

        <ul class="level0 collapsible" style="margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 10px;display: block" expanded="1">
```

`<span class="plus-right"...` gets the `style="...;background-position: right center"`.

`<ul class="level0"...` gets `expanded="1"` and  `style="...;display:block"`

---

If this doesn't work for you, it would be really helpful to see a live version of your code. (The fiddle, lacking JS and CSS isn't enough)

Comment: I did exactly the same thing but it doesn't work. (Of course I refresh the cache but nothing...)

Comment: It sounds like we'll need to see more of your site to aide you further.

Comment: @capola You have to execute Codnitive.expand() after the script is initialized. If it's not working I suggest you view your console for errors.

Comment: @Anagio Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null 127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/:326
Codnitive.expand 127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/:326
(anonymous function) 127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/:346

Comment: Did you use getElementById

Comment: @Anagio Sure, I use exactly `code`  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Codnitive.expand(document.getElementById('the-menu-parent-element-id'))
  </script>`/code`

Comment: @Capola remove the code, if you need the first menu to expand on load. Just use jQuery. View the menu when expanded and collapsed to see what CSS styles are being applied, then use jQuery to expand the menu when the page loads.

Comment: I just found that this functionality is available in Ultra version of sidebar navigation which is 45USD. Is it possible that the developer has reduced this somehow?

Comment: @capola don't pay for it, just use jQuery it's a menu client side in the browser that just need to be expanded.

Comment: @Anagio How can I do it with jQuery? I added the HTML above, could you post your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though i'm not sure which parent it's setting to block. I assume it's the first `<li>` tag above the a tag since the span tag isn't a parent

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-1').css( "display", "block" );
});
```

See if this is how you want it http://jsfiddle.net/6VSUm/

Comment: In fact that is what I am looking for, but it seems that the jQuery can't override the collapse function and the menu stay again collapsed. I inserted the jQuery script just after the Codnitive's script.

Comment: check my updated code try with .ready() this executes once the dom is fully loaded after everything I believe has fired it should run

Comment: Your jQuery isn't right. `.nav-1` is the `<li>` not the `<ul>`. However, I don't think fixing the selector (`'.nav-1 ul'`) will be enough to resolve the issue.

Comment: @whitehat101 the first parent of the `a` tag which he says `WANT TO BE EXPANDED BY DEFAULT` has `this.parentNode` which I think is the first `<li>` above it. If that's not correct they can easily traverse up the dom to find the selector needed to expand

Comment: That is (partially) correct, but you need to reread the `expand` function. `parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block"` The `<li>` does not get the style applied to it.

Comment: Moreover, code like that will leave the UI in an inconstant state. When the user clicks to hide the menu, it checks the `expaned` attribute, and it will incorrectly believe that the menu is collapsed, and re-expand it. A second click, will close it.  Not to mention that the expand/collapse handle will be wrong, until clicked. --- assuming your code works as you intended, not as you wrote it.